# return index of array inside api array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api

I am trying to use the index number of an element in an array to show the number of the test for a corresponding score.
I'm using a `for` loop, the issue is, when printed I get the index number of ALL the test scores from all objects.

```
let testIndex = [];

function testNum() {
  for (let i = 0; i < student.grades.length; i++) {
    testIndex.push(i + 1);
  };
  return testIndex;
}
return ({
  student.grades.map((grade) => {
    return (
      <div className = 'd-flex flex-column'>
        Test {testNum()}
        {student.grades.indexOf() + 1}
        {grade}
      </div>
    )
  })
});
```

Here is my object:

```
{
  "students": [{
        "city": "Fush\u00eb-Muhurr",
        "company": "Yadel",
        "email": "iorton0@imdb.com",
        "firstName": "Ingaberg",
        "grades": ["78", "100", "92", "86", "89", "88", "91", "87"],
        "id": "1",
        "lastName": "Orton",
        "skill": "Oracle"
      }, {
        "city": "Sanghan",
        "company": "Avamm",
        "email": "cboards1@weibo.com",
        "firstName": "Clarke",
        "grades": ["75", "89", "95", "93", "99", "82", "89", "76"],
        "id": "2",
        "lastName": "Boards",
        "skill": "Sports"
      }, {
        "city": "Kugesi",
        "company": "Skalith",
        "email": "lromanet2@wired.com",
        "firstName": "Laurens",
        "grades": ["88", "90", "79", "82", "81", "99", "94", "73"],
        "id": "3",
        "lastName": "Romanet",
        "skill": "Employee Handbooks"
      }
   ]
 };
```

I want it to print out as:

```
Test 1 78
Test 2 100
Test 3 92
// ... and so on
```

I figured using the index number would be the easiest way to do this?

what I'm getting with current code:

```
Test 1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678: 0 78
Test 1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678: 0 100
Test 1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678: 0 92
Test 1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678: 0 86
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the current index as the second argument of map, so you can use that.

```
{student.grades.map((grade, index) => {
        return (
          <div className='d-flex flex-column'>Test {index + 1} {grade}</div>
        )
      })}
)
```